# Print the contents in a DIV

Tags: javascript, node.js

Whats the best way to print the output of javascript in a DIV?

**For example:**

i have this code that will give me a random number, like "95"

```
<script>
    var i = 0,
        howManyTimes = 500;

function f() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 93;
    i++;
    if (i < howManyTimes) {
        setTimeout(f, 2000);
    }
}
f(); //  start the loop
</script>
```

How i can use this output here, in this div:

```
   <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: {HERE}%;" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">{ANDHERE}
```

Comment: `document.querySelector('.progress-bar').style.width = yourWidth + 'px'` and `document.querySelector('.progress-bar').innerText = yourText`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below code.

I have kept the element fetching `var element = document.querySelector("#demo")` outside the function block. This will avoid creating this variable multiple times in recursive call and improve performance.

```js
var i = 0,
  howManyTimes = 500;
var element = document.querySelector("#demo");

function f() {
    var randomVal = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 93;
    i++;
    if (i < howManyTimes) {
        setTimeout(f, 2000);
    }
    element.style.width = randomVal + "px";
    element.innerHTML = randomVal;
}
f(); //  start the loop
```

```css
.progress-bar {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo" class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use the [dom property of style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)

```js
var i = 0,
  howManyTimes = 500;
var elem = document.querySelector('.progress-bar')

function f() {
  let val = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 93;
  i++;
  if (i < howManyTimes) {
    setTimeout(f, 2000);
  }
  elem.style.width = val+'px';
  elem.innerHTML = val
}
f();
```

```css
.progress-bar{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
```